# Design error in pdf export - Dompdf/tcpdf

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, dompdf

I am developing a travel portal and its essential to make a pdf ticket for the booking. I used Dompdf and tcPdf. But there is design error in exported pdf from both libraries.

**This is my actual HTML Design**
[image]

**This is the generated PDF**

[image]

> My HTML Design Code

```
<table class="col-xs-12 other-table" style="text-align:left">
  <tr>
    <td>TICKET ID</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span>LD324865</span></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>PACKAGE NAME</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span>LAKSHADWEEP SUMMER PACKAGE</span></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DATE OF BOOKING</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span>28 May 2016</span></td>
    <td>DATE OF JOURNEY</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span>31 May 2016</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<style>
.grey-color{
color:#666; 
}
.total-cost{font-size:18px}
.address{
font-size:11px;
}
.heading{
border-bottom:1px #CCCCCC solid;
}
.package-name{
font-size:15px;
margin:15px 0px;
}
.package-name span{
    padding:10px !important;background:#EAEAEA;
}
.table{font-size:14px}
.other-table td{padding: 12px 0px !important;font-size:12px}
.other-table span{background:#EAEAEA;padding:16px !important;}
.uppercase{text-transform:uppercase !important;}

</style>
```

> PHP Code for generating PDF

```
<?php 
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';


// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$html = file_get_contents('holiday.html');
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);


// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
?>
```

How to get a correct pdf design ?
I don't want any paid library. Is there any other PHP PDF library to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dompdf does not currently (up through and inluding 0.7.0) have good support for padding on inline elements. you can switch to a block element (a P or DIV) and see better results.

With 0.7.0 you can also fix the styling by setting your span display style to inline-block.

Comment: I tried making my layout using div,span and p. Now its not bad!